# LCDM epoch or point where it fails

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, big-bang, nucleosynthesis

Nobody denies the currently success of the LCDM of cosmology. Recently, I wondered myself if there is a point or epoch (beyond the space-time singularity) where it breaks down. Does it fail at phase transitions? At the point where the CMB is created? At the dark ages?

In other words, where is the current limit of time where the LCDM is applied. I would guess is either the CMB and/or the dark ages/reionization era where our tests are not so stringent. But I am not sure if that is right or not.

Answer (score 3):

Actually recombination is one of the times where $\Lambda$CDM is tested *best*, since we have direct evidence of what the Universe looked like when the CMB formed.

A "rule of thumb" you will hear frequently in the cosmology community is that $\Lambda$CDM is well tested from the present epoch back until Big Bang Nucleosynthesis (BBN). Along the way are many different observational probes that all point to the same picture and parameters of $\Lambda$CDM (modulo some [Hubble tension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubble%27s_law#Determining_the_Hubble_constant)). Before BBN, there are no *direct* observational probes of the Universe's history. It is widely (but not universally) held that inflation produced the initial conditions that feed into the $\Lambda$CDM model, but the physics of inflation itself is quite underdetermined from observations.

So, many but by no means all cosmologists believe something like inflation happened and produced an initial matter power spectrum. This evolved until BBN, where we have our first observational tests. After that, $\Lambda$CDM is probed in various ways that provide a largely consistent picture, although there are some issues like the Hubble tension that still need to be resolved. Before inflation, no one really has any idea what happened. (In some models inflation is replaced with a series of bouncing Universes, and Roger Penrose has a "Conformal Cyclic Cosmology" model -- theorists are free to imagine many things here.)